# What is the proper way to reference TypeScript class methods and properties from the constructor?

Tags: typescript, class

I have a TypeScript class with a constructor. My goal is to change the "bar" property value by invoking the "baz" method inside the constructor. But, the baz method seems to have no effect. After the baz method is invoked, I'm expecting the bar property value to be "blue". Instead, the value remains "red".

```
class Foo {
  bar:string = "red";

  baz():void {
    this.bar = "blue";
  };

  constructor() {
    var bar = this.bar;
    var baz = this.baz;
    baz();
    console.log(bar) // logs "red";
  }
}

var x = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing a local copy of `bar`. It is assigned to "red". After calling `baz`, then `this.bar` should be "blue" but the local `bar` is still "red".

Try this:

```
constructor() {
    // var bar = this.bar; // unnecessary
    // var baz = this.baz; // unnecessary
    this.baz();
    console.log(this.bar) // should be "blue";
  }
```

Comment: That's just half the answer here.

Answer (score 4):

There's actually two problems going on here:

1. Your reference to `this.baz` isn't bound correctly.
2. You're logging an object you »copied« before you called the method.

Let's tackle #2 first. Basically, you're doing this:

```
let value = "red";
let bar = value;
value = "blue";
console.log(bar); // logs red
```

It's pretty obvious why it would not log blue instead since you reassigned the reference. This doesn't »propagate« to `bar`. The same happens in your code:

```
var bar = this.bar;
// … reassign this.bar, but not bar
console.log(bar); // will not log the updated value
```

---

The second problem is that you need to use

```
var baz = this.baz.bind(this);
```

in order to get the context right (or just call `this.baz()` directly).